# How to access MY Instagram from API (see hashtag 'ed media)

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to collect all media that use a specific hashtag from Instagram to run a hashtag contest for an event.

I have tried the Instagram API and I can collect the media through it, while in sandbox mode, but only the public ones. I want to be able to collect also those belonging to PRIVATE users that I already follow.

If my application passes the review process, will I be able to see the media that people I follow have posted? (like on the official Instagram APP?) Has the review process indeed paused due to the latest news?

Is there any 3rd party APP that has already been reviewed or any other solution that allows me to access the private data?

I just want to check for media that use a specific hashtag every 15-60 seconds and save them to a database based on submission time.

*Edit: Another option would be to publish a minimal application that only reads the users' self media. This way everyone who participates would need to provide access to my Application and then I would be able to verify if they have posted using the hashtag.
My main concerns are:*

1. Are applications requiring only the basic scope reviewed?
2. Can an application like this pass review? In the API terms it states they do not accept apps for one-off projects (like a campaign)*

Answer (score 0):

Instagram is not accepting any new apps that use the `public_content` permission for review. So you won't be able to get your app out of Sandbox mode if you are using that permission. There are a few 3rd party apps that have been granted permission for that, but even they will stop working when the `public_content` permission is deprecated in December 2018.

As per https://instagram.com/developer and https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog

Another option would be to use something like the hashtag campaign feature from SnapWidget that could be used to create a contest.

Comment: The hashtag campaign looks interesting. The issue is though that I need to get the following info:
1. How many time the hashtag has been used
2. By who users
3. The timestamp of each post.

Does SnapWidget offer an API with these info, or is there any other application offering the above functionality?
(please also check the edit in my initial question)